# How do astronomical spectrometers select a single object from the field of view?

Tags: spectroscopy, telescopes

The JWST is said to have a capability to observe the spectrum of the light from individual stars and exoplanets. The field of view of JWST is usually filled with hundreds or thousands of objects. How would it select the light from one of the objects to be sent to the spectrometer?

I can think of some possibilities.

1. Mechanical light blockers like used to observe the corona of the Sun. These are impossible for the high number of objects in the field of view.
2. A single aperture that blocks all light except from the intended star. It can be moved in x and y directions along the image to select one of the objects. This doesn't look feasible because each object of interest may be of different size, so we can't determine the size of the aperture, except if it's opening can also be adjusted.
3. Having an aperture of adjustable size and aligning the telescope so that the object of interest is seen through the aperture.
4. Using an array of MEMS mirrors in the focal plane to only guide the light from the object of interest to the spectrometer, like in projectors.

Comment: I'd have to track down the references, but even a long time ago (1990's?) folks used precision milled plates with fiber optics inserted at just the right places to install in the focal plane of the telescope to obtain the spectra of multiple specific objects at once (one fiber to one spectrometer, lots of fibers and spectrometers).

Comment: Maybe you'd get more answers if you asked on the [Space Exploration StackExchange site](https://space.stackexchange.com/).